# Assign value to a grouped dataframe based on dates of second dataframe

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataset of water quality sample results that I would like to assign grades (Prelim_dql) based on results of quality control samples.

I have two different data frames. One for water quality samples and one for QC results.

The water quality samples are batched into groups. This simplified example version has two groups (grp1 and grp2).

```
Group   ID  Result  DateTime    Prelim_dql
grp1    1   218.7   7/14/2009   
grp1    2   1119.9  7/20/2009   
grp1    3   128.1   7/27/2009   
grp1    4   192.4   8/5/2009    
grp1    5   524.7   8/18/2009   
grp1    6   325.5   9/2/2009    
grp2    7   19.2    7/13/2009   
grp2    8   15.26   7/16/2009   
grp2    9   14.58   8/13/2009   
grp2    10  13.06   8/13/2009   
grp2    11  12.56   10/12/2009
```

The simplified version of the quality control samples looks like this:

```
Group QCID  DateTime    DQL
grp1    1   7/26/2009   A
grp1    2   7/29/2009   C
grp2    3   7/14/2009   A
grp2    4   9/10/2009   B
grp2    5   10/12/2009  A
```

I would like to be able to assign the sample result grades based on the date range of the quality control samples. If the sample date is before the first QC result, then I would like to assign the DQL from the first QC result. If the sample date is between two QC results, I would like to assign the lower of the two DQLs (A being highst grade, C being the lowest). If the result is after the last QC result, assign the DQL from the last QC result.

In this scenario, I would like to get this result:

```
Group ID    Result  DateTime    Prelim_dql
grp1    1   218.7   7/14/2009   A
grp1    2   1119.9  7/20/2009   A
grp1    3   128.1   7/27/2009   C
grp1    4   192.4   8/5/2009    C
grp1    5   524.7   8/18/2009   C
grp1    6   325.5   9/2/2009    C
grp2    7   19.2    7/13/2009   A
grp2    8   15.26   7/16/2009   B
grp2    9   14.58   8/13/2009   B
grp2    10  13.06   8/13/2009   B
grp2    11  12.56   10/12/2009  A
```

I have searched and searched, but i just can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: *"This simplified example version has two groups (grp1 and grp2)."* But your expected outcome has `grp3`, `grp4`, `grp5`, `grp6`. Is your expected outcome consistent with your sample data?

Comment: *"I would like to assign the lower of the two DQLs"*. So how is "lower" defined? `A < B < C`?

Comment: That was a mistake as I was simplifying the data down. I have fixed it. Thanks.

A highest, C is lowest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be achieved using `sqldf` and `dplyr` packages. 
Note that name of column `Group` has been changed to `Grp` as `Group` is not a valid name in `sqldf`.

Approach:
Modify `QC` dataframe so that each row defines applicable date range and added one column to indicate that row contains `max` date for group. Join this modified `QC` with `samples` to get desired result.

```
#Data to be used are

samples <- read.table(text = "Grp   ID  Result  DateTime
grp1    1   218.7   7/14/2009   
grp1    2   1119.9  7/20/2009   
grp1    3   128.1   7/27/2009   
grp1    4   192.4   8/5/2009    
grp1    5   524.7   8/18/2009   
grp1    6   325.5   9/2/2009    
grp2    7   19.2    7/13/2009   
grp2    8   15.26   7/16/2009   
grp2    9   14.58   8/13/2009   
grp2    10  13.06   8/13/2009   
grp2    11  12.56   10/12/2009", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

samples$DateTime = as.POSIXct(samples$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

QC <- read.table(text = "Grp QCID  DateTime    DQL
grp1    1   7/26/2009   A
grp1    2   7/29/2009   C
grp2    3   7/14/2009   A
grp2    4   9/10/2009   B
grp2    5   10/12/2009  A", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

QC$DateTime = as.POSIXct(QC$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

# Add a column for end of applicable day of a DQL using lag
# Add another column to indicate a row contains Max date for that group
QC_Mod <- QC %>% group_by(Grp) %>%
  mutate(ApplicableAfter = lag(DateTime)) %>%
  mutate(IsMaxDate = ifelse(DateTime == max(DateTime),1,0)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

# Join the data.frames to find DQL value
sqldf("SELECT samples.Grp, samples.ID,  samples.Result,  samples.DateTime , QC_Mod.DQL as Prelim_dql 
      FROM samples, QC_Mod
      WHERE samples.Grp == QC_Mod.Grp AND 
      (
      (samples.DateTime <= QC_Mod.DateTime AND QC_Mod.ApplicableAfter IS NULL) OR
      (QC_Mod.ApplicableAfter IS NOT NULL AND samples.DateTime > QC_Mod.ApplicableAfter AND samples.DateTime <= QC_Mod.DateTime) OR
      (samples.DateTime > QC_Mod.DateTime AND QC_Mod.IsMaxDate == 1)
      )")

#  Result
#  Grp ID  Result   DateTime       Prelim_dql
#  1  grp1  1  218.70 2009-07-14          A
#  2  grp1  2 1119.90 2009-07-20          A
#  3  grp1  3  128.10 2009-07-27          C
#  4  grp1  4  192.40 2009-08-05          C
#  5  grp1  5  524.70 2009-08-18          C
#  6  grp1  6  325.50 2009-09-02          C
#  7  grp2  7   19.20 2009-07-13          A
#  8  grp2  8   15.26 2009-07-16          B
#  9  grp2  9   14.58 2009-08-13          B
#  10 grp2 10   13.06 2009-08-13          B
#  11 grp2 11   12.56 2009-10-12          A
```

Comment: AMAZING. This works great. Thank you so much, you saved the day!